# How to stop a loop after finding n elements javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am writing a quick bit of code which find the first three even numbers in a random length of random numbers in an array.

```
  const getEven = (array) => {
  const evenArr = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (index % 2 != 0) {
      evenArr.push(array[index]);
    }
  }
  console.log(evenArr);
};

getEven([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
Output = [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

The question I have is, once it finds the first three even elements the loop continues to run, how can I stop it after finding the first three elements and is there a more efficient way of doing this?

I could use a filter but decided to go traditional and wrote a for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 if (index % 2 != 0 && evenArr.length<3)
```

Comment: This is really clean, and I never even thought of it! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may just add `break` statement with your desired condition:

```
 const getEven = (array) => {
  const evenArr = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (index % 2 !== 0) {
      evenArr.push(array[index]);
    }
    
    if (evenArr.length === 3) {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(evenArr);
};

getEven([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
Output = [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks Sergey. I did not know you could use a break with conditions. Great to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

With your current approach, the easiest change would be to add `break` -statement to your loop:

```js
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (index % 2 != 0) {
      evenArr.push(array[index]);
      if (arrray.length >= 3) {
        break; // <= this will end the loop
      }
    }    
  }
```

It is also good to mention that your algorithm is collecting odd numbers not even numbers currently. SHould be `index % 2 === 0`.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. i.e. Even numbers are those numbers that can be divided into two equal groups or pairs and are exactly divisible by 2. For example, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, https://www.cuemath.com/numbers/even-numbers/

Comment: Exactly my point. The code is adding values to the array when they are not even. 

`ndex % 2 != 0` is true when the value is odd value. 

2 % 2 = 0 // even
3 % 2 = 1 // odd ==> != 0
4 % 2 = 0 // event

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `break`

```
   if (evenArr.length === 3) {
      break;
   }
```

or return

```
   if (evenArr.length === 3) {
      return;
   }
```

or better:

```
   if (evenArr.length === 3) {
      return evenArr
   }
```

Return not just stops the loop but the whole function

```
const getEven = (array) => {
  const evenArr = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (index % 2 != 0) evenArr.push(array[index]);
    if(evenArr.length === 3) return evenArr;
  }
  return evenArr
};
```